# keep the activity on screen even the lock button is pressed

Tags: android, lockscreen

I'm working on one project regarding calling.

**Problem:**

- When I dial number and call, I can see a calling screen.Everything
  works fine until I press the lock screen button.
- When I unlock my phone, I can see my calling screen for while but
  then it goes to the dialing screen (in which it requires a number to 
  dial and then to call again).
- Even though dialing screen is active the call is still continue(which
  is dial before lock) and it's working properly but then I can't
  access my calling screen to end the call. (disconnect call)

**Here's my code :**

```
  private void stayAwakeOnLockScreen() {

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code to add flags

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

and then in manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".yourActivity"
    android:showOnLockScreen="true" >
```